# If document URL indexOf

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have some search page link: `www.example.com/search.php?search=search_word`, I am tried to make a default search URL. If people only type `www.example.com/search.php` via the browser, make a default URL as `www.example.com/search.php?search=aaa`. My code does not work.

```
<script src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var currneturl = document.URL;
if(!document.URL.indexOf('?')){
    document.URL = currneturl + '?search=aaa';
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: "My code not work" doesn't describe an observed behaviour and the way that it differs from the desired behaviour

Comment: Why are you doing this with JavaScript instead of PHP?

Comment: @Quentin, how to use `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` to do this?

Comment: @yulichika — Why would you use that? Test if `$_GET['search']` is set and redirect (or just carry on as normal by using a different value) if it isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns `-1` if the string is not found, and `-1` is a truthy value such that `!-1` is `false`. You need to explicitly test for -1:

```
if (document.URL.indexOf('?') === -1) {
```

Comment: nnnnnn, both method still not work, can u test it for me? just a short code. thanks.

Comment: Did you just copy/paste? For some reason nnnnn has three =, should only be 2

Comment: @ZeekLTK - "For some reason"? I have `===` because that is the JS operator that I feel is most appropriate here.